# Mass Assignment in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am following railscasts 196 episode and i try exactly what he has, but i am having the following error

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in SurveysController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: questions_attributes
Rails.root: /home/jean/rail/surveysays
```

Here my code so far

Survey Form

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <% if @survey.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |bf|%>
    <%= bf.label :content, "Question" %><br />
    <%= bf.text_area :content, :rows=> 3 %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Survey Relationship

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Question Relationship

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  attr_accessible :content, :survey_id
end
```

New Controller

```
def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    3.times {@survey.questions.build }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @survey }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your class to this

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
  attr_accessible :name, :questions_attributes
end
```

look for topic "Using with attr_accessible" [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for more information

Comment: Well it works, and i can't accept the answer for an other 6 min, meanwhile is it a new feature to ruby?